# How to divide LaTeX table cells vertically?

Tags: tables

I want my table to have separated cells. Basically double lines but I can't figure how to have horizontal lines disconnected. I tried \hline and \cline but those connect too.

This is best I can do:

[image]

This is how I want my table to look:
[image]

```
\begin{tabular}{|c||c||c||c|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|c||}{First Cell}&
  Second Cell&
  Third Cell\\
  \hline
  \hline
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}} Data\\ Data\\ Data\\
  \end{tabular}&
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    Data\\
    Data\\
    Data\\
  \end{tabular}&
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    Data\\
    Data\\
    Data\\
  \end{tabular}&
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    Data\\
    Data\\
    Data\\
  \end{tabular}\\

  \hline

\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! What have you tried? Please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) demonstrating your set-up.

Comment: I also tried putting every cell in its nested tabular environement but that way it messes up spaceing between cells of primary table

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this with the [hhline](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hhline) package:

[image: Result]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hhline}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c||c||c||c|}
  \hhline{|--||-||-|}
  \multicolumn{2}{|c||}{First Cell}&
  Second Cell&
  Third Cell\\
  \hhline{=:t:=::=::=:}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}} Data\\ Data\\ Data\\
  \end{tabular}&
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    Data\\
    Data\\
    Data\\
  \end{tabular}&
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    Data\\
    Data\\
    Data\\
  \end{tabular}&
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    Data\\
    Data\\
    Data\\
  \end{tabular}\\
  \hhline{=::=::=::=:}
  More data &
  More data &
  More data &
  More data\\
  \hhline{|-||-||-||-|}

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array,hhline}

\begin{document}

\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c||c||c||c|}
  \hhline{|--||-||-|}
  \multicolumn{2}{|c||}{First Cell}&
  Second Cell&
  Third Cell\\
  \hhline{=:t:=::=::=}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}} Data\\ Data\\ Data\\
  \end{tabular}&
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    Data\\
    Data\\
    Data\\
  \end{tabular}&
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    Data\\
    Data\\
    Data\\
  \end{tabular}&
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    Data\\
    Data\\
    Data\\
  \end{tabular}\\
  \hhline{|-||-||-||-|}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to construct that table with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}

\begin{NiceTabular}{cccc}
\Block{1-2}{First Cell} && Second Cell & Third cell \\
\Block{3-1}{} Data & \Block{3-1}{} Data & \Block{3-1}{} Data & \Block{3-1}{} Data \\
Data & Data & Data & Data \\
Data & Data & Data & Data \\
More Data & More Data & More Data & More Data \\
\CodeAfter
  \TikzEveryCell{offset=1pt,draw}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the first code]

It's also possible to add rounded corners:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}

\begin{NiceTabular}{cccc}
\Block{1-2}{First Cell} && Second Cell & Third cell \\
\Block{3-1}{} Data & \Block{3-1}{} Data & \Block{3-1}{} Data & \Block{3-1}{} Data \\
Data & Data & Data & Data \\
Data & Data & Data & Data \\
More Data & More Data & More Data & More Data \\
\CodeAfter
  \TikzEveryCell{offset=1pt,draw,rounded corners}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]